# Javascript error when opening popup window in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, mootools, mootools1.2

I am getting the following js error on the console when attempting to open a popup window using MooDialog.Request.   It works in IE7/IE8 and Chrome, but not IE9 and possibly later IE versions.  I have seen some similar questions related to this, but not concerning a popup.

```
SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5) 
mootools-1.2.4-core.js, line 122 character 47
```

Here is the code where I am making the call to MooDialog.Request...

```
var formid = 127;  // for the purposes of this example
var dialog = new MooDialog.Request('viewoptionsform.cfm?form=' + formid,
                null,
                {
                   size: {width: 400, height: 350},
                   useScrollBar: false,
                   closeOnOverlayClick: false,
                   disposeOnClose: false
                });
```

Has anyone else experienced anything similar or have any suggestions for me to try?  Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Using mootools v1.2.4 which is required for MooDialog

Comment: That version of MooTools **predates** the release of IE9 by about 2 years. It's not at all unlikely that some subsequent MooTools release would have fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you not upgrade the MooTools version? Better to update the plugin and use a more recent MooTools version. Is it Arian's MooDialog? then you could upgrade to a later version...

Comment: It's not easy to upgrade as it would require substantial regression testing.  However, there may be a possibility that the project will have funding to rewrite the software, in which case Mootools will be replaced with jQuery.

Comment: @jtb if you can make a jsFiddle reproducing the problem would be easier to help...

Comment: An upgrade to MooTools v1.2.5 for the specfic web page only has resolved the issue.  Thanks for your advice.